# Running gradle test tasks in Microsoft App-V5.1 virtualized environment

Tags: gradle, junit5, appv

I'm very new to App-V, which is evaluated in my office. 
I have a Selenium test suite written in JUnit5 and can launch it as gradle `test` task using gradle-wrapper.  My final goal is to run this on App-V5.1 virtualized environment, similar as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38900941/).

As followed [the link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2848278/how-to-launch-processes-inside-the-app-v-5-0-virtualized-environment) which was mentioned the answer, I tried to launch `cmd.exe` within the App-V environment, and it seeded works.  Then, I tried to do this:

```
./gradlew --no-daemon clean test
```

Then the `testClasses` phase works perfectly, but in the `test` phase, I got an error like:

```
Could not write standard input into: Gradle Worker 1.
java.io.IOException: The pipe is being closed
   ...
```

(Sorry I couldn't show you the actual error log due to security reason, but it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548085/).)

May I wrong something?  What's the right way to launch a gradle test in App-V env?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching cmd.exe from within the virtual bubble? I find the best way to do this is to create a shortcut to cmd.exe during sequencing and use this to troubleshoot.

If your process works within the bubble, the solution may be as simple as allowing Local Interaction. Have a read [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gladiatormsft/2013/09/11/app-v-on-com-isolation-and-interaction/) about that.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, running cmd.exe (and gradle tasks as a subprocess) within the virtual bubble, by creating shortcut with `/appvve:` option.  I'll check the doc you mentioned, thanks!

Comment: Did the gardle task work in these conditions? If so, this will indicate where the problem is. A further question, did you run the gardle task during sequencing and did it work then?